# extending complex type in XSD at runtime

Tags: xsd

I am creating an XSD schema which is included into a bigger schema with many other xsd.
Those other XSD are changed programmatically and therefore I need to do the following:

I defined a complex type which extends another type as follow:

```
<xs:element name="Device" maxOccurs="unbounded">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:extension base="myType">
            <xs:attribute name="label" use="required"/>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and so far... so good...
the problem is that now i would like to do the same but not extending myType but extending something which name is contained in some other attribute in the code.
Is there any way of doing something like this??

I would express this in Xpath with somethink like

```
<xs:extension base="./../../[@myType]">
```

but I admit... I am completely guessing...
Does anyone knows is something similar is doable and in case using what?
I am not sure xsd is "clever-enough" to handle something like this at runtime...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve anything like this using XSD, or other modeling languages that I am using frequently, such as UML, ER or AOM.

Comment: this is what i expect... but yet i gave it a desperate try..:(